# Django serializer field value base on other field in the same serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have the following serializer.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    comment_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    commented = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_comment_count(self, obj):
        # Assume the method can retrieve the comment count correctly
        return x
    def get_commented(self, obj):
        # Return True if comment count > 0, else False
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment_count', 'commented']
```

Any suggestions for the coding in `get_commented` method? I code something like `return comment_count > 0` but fail.

Comment: How about: `return self.get_comment_count(obj) > 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the django object using obj, so I think the code will be something like :

```
obj.comment_set.count()
```

to get the comment count and then :

```
return self.get_comment_count(obj) > 0
```

as Pang said to implement get_commented

Comment: Wouldn't this cause multiple database requests, although one would be sufficient?